# Django: continuing block after exception

Tags: python, django

How to continue the execution of a block after an exception.
I have two vmware servers running
I have created two functions, one that refreshes the information coming from the server and the other that populates the database.

Except that when one of the servers does not respond
an error occurs and the refresh is not done.

```
def vm_refresh(request):
    vmware_list = Vmware.objects.all()
    for i in vmware_list:
        vmwarepopulatevm(i)
        i.save()
    # ...

def vcsapopulatevm(vmware):
    # ...
    req1 = vmrequestsget()
    if 'value' in req1.json().keys():
        for i in my req1.json()['value']:
            VirtualMachine.objects.update_or_create(vm=i['vm']
                                                    vmware=vmware,
                                                    defaults=i
                                                    )
    # ...
```

I tried somethink like this and it's works

```
try:
    vmwarepopulatevm(i)
    i.save()
except Exception:
    pass
```

But I want to create a generic function because I will have to use it more often

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Make sure you understand all the conditions that would cause `vmwarepopulatevm(i)` to throw an exception, and handle accordingly.  I'd consider putting the try block inside the `vcsapopulatevm()` function, which may make it 'more generic' if I'm properly understanding what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, there is no exception to catch. So I created a function check_vcsa that check is the vcsa is up or down and return a status like 200 or 400.
After in vm_refresh I just put a condition like `if check_vcsa(i.pk) != 200: pass
else:
vcsapopulatevm(i)`....